# How to create invoice when order created programmatically in magento1

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have created order by some reference code and code for create invoice but invoice is not creating only order creating. i want to show invoice in invoice tab also after generating. please find my code below :

```
    <?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

$id=1058; // get Customer Id
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);

$transaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction');
$storeId = $customer->getStoreId();
$reservedOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getEntityType('order')->fetchNewIncrementId($storeId);

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
->setIncrementId($reservedOrderId)
->setStoreId($storeId)
->setQuoteId(0)
->setGlobal_currency_code('INR')
->setBase_currency_code('INR')
->setStore_currency_code('INR')
->setOrder_currency_code('INR');
//Set your store currency USD or any other

// set Customer data
$order->setCustomer_email($customer->getEmail())
->setCustomerFirstname($customer->getFirstname())
->setCustomerLastname($customer->getLastname())
->setCustomerGroupId($customer->getGroupId())
->setCustomer_is_guest(0)
->setCustomer($customer);

// set Billing Address
$billing = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
$billingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
->setStoreId($storeId)
->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_BILLING)
->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
->setCustomerAddressId($customer->getDefaultBilling())
->setCustomer_address_id($billing->getEntityId())
->setPrefix($billing->getPrefix())
->setFirstname($billing->getFirstname())
->setMiddlename($billing->getMiddlename())
->setLastname($billing->getLastname())
->setSuffix($billing->getSuffix())
->setCompany($billing->getCompany())
->setStreet($billing->getStreet())
->setCity($billing->getCity())
->setCountry_id($billing->getCountryId())
->setRegion($billing->getRegion())
->setRegion_id($billing->getRegionId())
->setPostcode($billing->getPostcode())
->setTelephone($billing->getTelephone())
->setFax($billing->getFax());
$order->setBillingAddress($billingAddress);

$shipping = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();
$shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
->setStoreId($storeId)
->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING)
->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
->setCustomerAddressId($customer->getDefaultShipping())
->setCustomer_address_id($shipping->getEntityId())
->setPrefix($shipping->getPrefix())
->setFirstname($shipping->getFirstname())
->setMiddlename($shipping->getMiddlename())
->setLastname($shipping->getLastname())
->setSuffix($shipping->getSuffix())
->setCompany($shipping->getCompany())
->setStreet($shipping->getStreet())
->setCity($shipping->getCity())
->setCountry_id($shipping->getCountryId())
->setRegion($shipping->getRegion())
->setRegion_id($shipping->getRegionId())
->setPostcode($shipping->getPostcode())
->setTelephone($shipping->getTelephone())
->setFax($shipping->getFax());

$order->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress)
->setShipping_method('flatrate_flatrate');
/*->setShippingDescription($this->getCarrierName('flatrate'));*/
/*some error i am getting here need to solve further*/

//you can set your payment method name here as per your need
$orderPayment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment')
->setStoreId($storeId)
->setCustomerPaymentId(0)
->setMethod('purchaseorder')
->setPo_number(' â€“ ');
$order->setPayment($orderPayment);

// let say, we have 2 products
//check that your products exists
//need to add code for configurable products if any
$subTotal = 0;
$products = array(
    '1' => array(
    'qty' => 2
    ),
    '2' => array(
    'qty' => 1
    )
);

foreach ($products as $productId=>$product) {
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$rowTotal = $_product->getPrice() * $product['qty'];
$orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
->setStoreId($storeId)
->setQuoteItemId(0)
->setQuoteParentItemId(NULL)
->setProductId($productId)
->setProductType($_product->getTypeId())
->setQtyBackordered(NULL)
->setTotalQtyOrdered($product['rqty'])
->setQtyOrdered($product['qty'])
->setName($_product->getName())
->setSku($_product->getSku())
->setPrice($_product->getPrice())
->setBasePrice($_product->getPrice())
->setOriginalPrice($_product->getPrice())
->setRowTotal($rowTotal)
->setBaseRowTotal($rowTotal);

$subTotal += $rowTotal;
$order->addItem($orderItem);
}

$order->setSubtotal($subTotal)
->setBaseSubtotal($subTotal)
->setGrandTotal($subTotal)
->setBaseGrandTotal($subTotal);

$transaction->addObject($order);
$transaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'place'));
$transaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'save'));
$transaction->save();

//code for invoice generation
$order_id = $order->getIncrementId();

$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order_id);
try {
if(!$order->canInvoice())
{
Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice.'));
}

$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();

if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice without products.'));
}

$invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
$invoice->register();
$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
->addObject($invoice)
->addObject($invoice->getOrder());

$transactionSave->save();
}
catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {

}
$invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(
Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE
);

echo "invoice generated successfully";
```

Anyone have an idea for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();
$invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE);
$invoice->register();
$invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
    ->addObject($invoice)
    ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
$transactionSave->save();
```

Notice the changes...

I've never used "purchaseorder" payment method, so I am not sure if using **CAPTURE_ONLINE** could make a difference. **CAPTURE_OFFLINE** will only fire pay() method for payment class, while online will fire capture() method before

The other change is:

```
$invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
```

Which is used in Magento API methods, when creating invoices

Comment: Thanks for your help. i have added your code and invoice created but invoice data is not coming in this tab : https://www.diigo.com/item/image/6aphk/5g6y   how can get here?

Comment: Well... it doesn't seem any problem with invoice generation then, maybe just reloading the page shows it?

Comment: I have cleared cache and check again some another orders but invoice id and their data is not showing here : https://www.diigo.com/item/image/6aphk/5g6y  do i  code something for getting data here ?

Comment: In a default installation invoice would appear there, if created with above code... if it doesn't appear I believe there will be some custom code interfering. You could open a new question to check that